# Maximum possible value for the probability of an event.

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider two events $A$ and $B$ with the following given conditions:

$$P(A)=0.4\quad\textrm{and}\quad P(B)=0.7$$

The maximum and minimum value of $P(A\cap B)$ are?

Note: $P(X)$ denotes probability of occurrence of event $X$ and the other symbols have their usual meanings as in set theory.

Comment: see [this for help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried so far? Please show us your approach to help us better understand your problem and help you in the best way possible.

Comment: I am not sure why someone down-voted your question and my answer. I think it is a reasonable question, and I think my answer is correct...

Answer (score 2):

Venn diagram might prove useful here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since $A \cap B \subset A$ and  $A \cap B \subset B$,

$$P(A \cap B) \leq \min(P(A),P(B)) = 0.4. $$

On the other hand

$$P(A^c \cup B^c) \leq P(A^c)+(B^c) = 0.6 +0.3 = 0.9 . $$

So

$$P(A \cap B) = 1- P((A \cap B)^c) = 1-P(A^c \cup B^c) \geq 1-0.9 = 0.1. $$

Now you can construct examples to show that both of these bounds can be attained (that is, in general, they are the best possible bounds).

Comment: I don't know why I have this as downvoted. If you edit your post, I can switch my downvote to an upvote.